# Why is this site still down when the domain was renewed almost a week ago?

Tags: domains, dns, whois, expires

The domain of interest was renewed a week ago, but the site is still down. Shouldn't the site be back up by now? (It's not my domain, it's a domain I wanted to buy but failed to get, and I'm asking for educational purposes). If the site never gets up within the year, even though the domain is set to Jan of next year, what could be some reasons why this is so?

> ```
> Domain Name: DANGEROUSCREATION.COM
> Registry Domain ID: 1388597680_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
> Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
> Registrar URL: http://www.publicdomainregistry.com
> Updated Date: 2018-01-27T15:43:21Z
> Creation Date: 2008-01-27T00:48:16Z
> Registry Expiry Date: 2019-01-27T00:48:16Z
> ```

Comment: "Registry Expiry Date: 2019-01-27T00:48:16Z" - Curious, where did you perform your Whois lookup? If I do a Whois lookup I see and expiry date of "2018-01-27T00:48:16Z" - the same timestamp that you've quoted, but "2018" instead of "2019". ie. it's not been renewed as far as I can tell?!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the whois, the domain has probably just been renewed:

```
Registry Expiry Date: 2019-01-27T00:48:16Z
Updated Date: 2018-01-27T15:43:21Z
Domain Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
```

Even if the registrar whois does not seem correctly updated (its expiration date is still in the past).

The website is not down, it resolves perfectly and displays a webpage. Maybe not the one you were expecting, but still it works.
The registrar or the owner decided to monetize traffic and put some parking page, as you can also infer from the name of the nameservers.

This happens sometimes around expiration (another reason why it is silly to wait for the last minute, see my other comments), and maybe when the domain was really renewed the previous nameservers were not put back correctly, if the monetization was not intentional.

Indeed if you look at the Wayback Archive you can see there was a "live" site (not a parking one° before, like: http://web.archive.org/web/20180103034130/http://dangerouscreation.com/
The nameservers seem to have been previously `ns1-sb5y.welcomesearchers.com` and `ns2-sb5y.welcomesearchers.com`.
(you can see changes for example here: https://completedns.com/dns-history/?domain=DANGEROUSCREATION.COM)
In fact there are still configured as authoritative for this domain and do resolve the website with IP `69.194.230.35`. If you force your local resolution to this IP in fact you will stil see the previous website.

So either the registrar forgot to put back the old nameservers or the owner just decided to not renew it and hence the registrar or another party is holding on the domain to monetize it.

There is no guarantee what will happen in a year. In fact the domain name could also be deleted at any time, like any other domain. So if this domain is really the one you want, and that you need it "soon" you will need to contact the current owner to see how it could sell it to you.

Otherwise, my stable advise, as sad as it may be, is just to choose another domain name, especially today with gTLDs you have so many options...

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a domain lifecycle and it goes as follows.

1. **The domain is available.**
   (While a domain name is in the 'Available' stage it can be registered by any person or organization via a domain registrar that operates under the tld authority.)
2. **The domain is active.**
   (When a domain is in this phase it means that it has been already registered and it is fully functional. Domains of the most common extensions can be registered for minimum 1 year and a maximum period of 10 years. During this state, the domain can be renewed any time but its maximum life period cannot be extended to a period longer than 10 years.)
3. **The domain has expired.**
   (Being in this phase the domain will no longer work and any website services via the domain will be no longer accessible via it. The domain will stay in this phase for about 45 days and can be renewed only by its owner. If the domain is renewed it will go back to the Active phase.)
4. **The domain is in Redemption/Grace Period.**
   (If a domain name is not renewed in the 45-day-period while being in the Expired state it will go into Redemption phase. Redemption period might vary depending on your domain registrar or domain extension but usually lasts for up to 30 days.  During this period the domain can be renewed only by its owner but additional fees will be applied depending on the registrar to reactivate the domain.)
5. **The domain is pending Deletion.**
   (In case you do not renew your domain name during the Expired or Redemption phase your domain will go into the Pending Deletion stage. Domains in Pending Deletion cannot be renewed and usually stay in this phase for up to 5 days until all records for the domain are removed from the domain authority zone.)
6. A. **The domain is available.**
   B. **The domain goes onto an auction**
   (Depending on the original domain registrar, the domain may be released and set back to Available status after the Pending Deletion phase. Still, some registrars might withhold the domain or/and list it on domain auction websites.)

Source: https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/getting-started/domain-life-cycle

Comment: First, this domain life cycle apply only to gTLDs. Then the 45 days after expiration is what registries give to registrars, but registrars can give far less to their clients. So there is no gain in waiting for the last time to renew since the new expiry date will be based on the old one and not when the operation is done. When in redemption the domain is already deleted in fact. So you do not renew it at this time you restore it in fact.

Comment: I do not agree with 6B. If the registrar wish to put the domain in auction it should do it before deleting it. Because first by deleting it if it needs it back it will need to first restore it, and a restore always cost far much than a renew at a registry (because a restore is considered an exceptional measure that should not happen frequently), and then as soon as it is deleted after pending deletion it can become available at the registry and then the registrar would have nothing to put in auction as the domain is not under its sponsorship anymore at all.

Answer (score 0):

Was the domain renewed by the original owner?  If not then there is no reason that the site would reappear.  The new owner would have to create their own site.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain was not renewed or the nameservers are not configured properly then the the site will appear to be down. Sometimes there just may be no site at the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Renewing tells you nothing about what goes on behind the scenes.  So, in general, a domain name should go back online after it has been renewed, but it doesn't HAVE to go back online.  behind the scenes, the owner could have still lost it to another party through an auction, the owner could still own the domain, but want to take it in another direction and removed the Name Servers, the domain could be suspended for some other reason, etc etc.

There isn't really any way for you to know as an outsider, though you can always ask the owner.